# Expressions synonymous to "vice versa"?

Tags: phrase-request

Are there more common, native, general expressions that describe given relationship occurring in reverse as well?

> "You know I love you. You tease me, you give me hints, give me hope, and then you shield yourself with that lie, you deny every feeling you displayed so far. Did you plan to break my heart from the very beginning?"
>
> "I'm sorry! I... I didn't! And it's not a lie!"
>
> I held her head by her hair, firmly, forcing her to look at me.
>
> "You are hurting me," she whimpered.
>
> **"And vice versa,"** I replied, releasing her.

What other expressions, preferably not foreign like "Vice versa" could I use in this place?
(note "so are you" might be misread as "You are hurting *yourself* too", replacing only "you"; I need a full reversal: I->You, You->Me)

Comment: Straight from the thesaurus: conversely, inversely, the other way round, contrariwise, oppositely, in reverse, reciprocally. You could say "*Right back at you.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use 'likewise'. It is certainly English in origin and indicates the reversal you want.

You could also consider a phrase such as, "So now you know how I feel," if that doesn't feel over-dramatic.

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are many contexts where _likewise_ is **not** a good replacement for _vice versa_ (something like _and the other way around_ might be better). That caveat said, I find _likewise_ to be an excellent suggestion in the context outlined in this question.